# Tiny C++ cross-platform GUI toolkit

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform

Which C++ cross-platform GUI toolkit gives smallest footprint with both static and dynamic builds? I don't need a very sophisticated GUI, just basic controls & widgets.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897228/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-simple-cross-platform-gui-in-c among several others.

Comment: Hi, it's not a dupe. I focus on footprint. Thanks for URL anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the smallest one I've heard of is [fltk](http://fltk.org)

Answer (score 3):

The Tk from [Tcl/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/) is well known of its small memory footprint. Details in [Memory Footprint Comparisons](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1131) on Tcl/Tk Wiki. Both, Tcl and Tk, are extremely simple to use with [C++/Tcl](http://cpptcl.sourceforge.net/) and [C++/Tk](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/) libraries. They were inspired by [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/)

Answer (score 3):

With the [Ecere SDK](http://ecere.com/), you can build a statically linked executable under 1 MB. A dynamic runtime library can also be built under 2 MB. Ecere runs in a variety of display drivers, including X11, GDI, OpenGL, Direct3D. It was originally designed for in-game GUIs, but it's now a rich general purpose cross-platform GUI toolkit.

The SDK comes with a compiler for the eC language, an OO language which compiles down to native code, that can be linked with C++ at the C level (i.e. extern "C").

eC shares many basic OO concepts and syntax of C++, but offers simpler, more elegant code, especially for GUI development: it has properties, instance virtual methods for events, you use '.' instead of '->' for accessing heap objects members. It still fully supports the entire C syntax, grammar and features. eC rids you of the pain of header files and prototypes as well, with a more modern import mechanism.

Comment: do you mind if asked to provide an answer to this question?: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25480619/1284631

Answer (score 1):

try [cegui](http://www.cegui.org.uk/).  It was designed for game guis, which have to be light (for console games).  I've never tried [fltk](http://fltk.org/).  It may be more suitable.

Comment: cegui has a rather big footprint. wouldn't recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

There are several minimal options in the long list of cross-platform C++ UI libraries here: https://philippegroarke.com/posts/2018/c++_ui_solutions/
I think you'd have to evaluate them yourself.