# good libraries for windows applications in c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, windows

I have been learning c++ for more than 8 months and I think I have got grip on every essential concept of c++. I have created some good console based application but now I want to build GUI application with good looking interface.

What are the some good free c++ libraries for beginners to develop GUI based windows applications?

Please also recommend some of the good tutorials available on web related to that library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/158667)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to make a simple cross platform GUI in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897228/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-simple-cross-platform-gui-in-c), [Gui toolkits, which should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/584734) and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the some good free c++ libraries

[Qt 4](http://qt.nokia.com).

> some of the good tutorials

[Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/). Tutorials can be found on [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/).